# Error "no matching mac found" with ubuntu 10.04 and github

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-10.04, github

I have a web application mounted on an old server with Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS and for a short time I have not been able to deploy it due to a problem that occurs with the connection to github to download the code:

```
no matching mac found: client
hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
server
hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The problem seems to be caused by a recent change in github that does not accept connections with old protocols, here they explain it:
https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/

This is the ssh version of my Ubuntu server:

```
ssh -V
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7.1, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
```

Which by the way does not support the -Q option that is proposed in some responses to similar questions that have not helped me to solve the problem.

```
ssh: illegal option -- Q
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-i identity_file] [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

The ssh_config file for my server is this:

```
#       $OpenBSD: ssh_config,v 1.34 2019/02/04 02:39:42 dtucker Exp $

# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h

Host *
        SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Could someone help me to fix this issue considering I am tied to that server running Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS? Thank you very much.

Comment: 10.04? Dude, upgrade the System to a supported device. As long this question is offtopic since questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Host *

MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256